# Installation issue for pygame on Mac M1 with Python 3.8

Tags: python, pygame

I am capable of installing pygame on a Mac M1 using: 
`pip install pygame==1.9.6` 
Despite the fact that no errors arise during installation, I get the following when trying to import `pygame`, for example:

```py
import pygame
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

When could be the source of this problem? I'm not precisely sure how I'd go about resolving this error, nor what it means to be exact.

**Edit**

If I try to install the latest version with: 
`pip install -U pygame` 
I get a long `gcc` error, which ends with the following:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-install-s7axfi8b/pygame_d79133ea00834293bb7b8163896e7345/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-install-s7axfi8b/pygame_d79133ea00834293bb7b8163896e7345/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-record-5eo2sjax/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/include/python3.8/pygame Check the logs for full command output.
```

Here's a summary of the full command output:

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.0.1.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pygame
  Building wheel for pygame (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-install-s7axfi8b/pygame_d79133ea00834293bb7b8163896e7345/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-install-s7axfi8b/pygame_d79133ea00834293bb7b8163896e7345/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-kgcdl1fg
       cwd: /private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-install-s7axfi8b/pygame_d79133ea00834293bb7b8163896e7345/
  Complete output (286 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  copying src_py/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/threads
  copying src_py/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/threads
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/_sdl2
  copying src_py/_sdl2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/_sdl2
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests
  copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests
  copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests
  copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests
...
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
  copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
  copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-...
  copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
  copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/__pyinstaller
  copying src_py/__pyinstaller/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/__pyinstaller
  copying src_py/__pyinstaller/hook-pygame.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/__pyinstaller
  running build_ext
  building 'pygame.imageext' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/src_c
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/include -arch arm64 -I/Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/include -arch arm64 -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/include/python3.8 -c src_c/imageext.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/src_c/imageext.o
  In file included from src_c/imageext.c:29:
  In file included from src_c/pygame.h:30:
  In file included from src_c/_pygame.h:36:
  In file included from /usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38:
  In file included from /usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:86:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/immintrin.h:14:
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:50:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);

  ...
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:525:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  
  ---
  For help with compilation see:
      https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
  To contribute to pygame development see:
      https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
  ---
  
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygame
  Running setup.py clean for pygame
Failed to build pygame
Installing collected packages: pygame
    Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-install-s7axfi8b/pygame_d79133ea00834293bb7b8163896e7345/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-install-s7axfi8b/pygame_d79133ea00834293bb7b8163896e7345/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-record-5eo2sjax/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/include/python3.8/pygame
         cwd: /private/var/folders/v8/xbqyyrhx7mxd_dcm9x9jf8tc0000gn/T/pip-install-s7axfi8b/pygame_d79133ea00834293bb7b8163896e7345/
    Complete output (286 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/threads
    copying src_py/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/threads
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/_sdl2
    copying src_py/_sdl2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/_sdl2
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests
...
3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py ->
...
test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> 
...
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> ...
build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-
3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
...
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> 
3.8/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/docs
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/setmodescale.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/font_viewer.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/audiocapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
...
    copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-
3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/examples
    creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/__pyinstaller
    copying src_py/__pyinstaller/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/__pyinstaller
    copying src_py/__pyinstaller/hook-pygame.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/pygame/__pyinstaller
    running build_ext
    building 'pygame.imageext' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/src_c
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/include -arch arm64 -I/Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/include -arch arm64 -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/ryanrudes/miniforge3/envs/ml/include/python3.8 -c src_c/imageext.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.8/src_c/imageext.o
    In file included from src_c/imageext.c:29:
    In file included from src_c/pygame.h:30:
    In file included from src_c/_pygame.h:36:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:86:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/immintrin.h:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:50:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:129:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:159:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:189:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:216:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:239:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:260:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:287:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:310:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:331:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:373:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:394:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:416:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:439:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:461:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:483:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:504:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:525:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Basically, this is an internal error that a user normally can't control. Make sure that you installed the latest version of Pygame. Looks like [Pygame is facing a lot of issues with M1 Macs](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2452).

Comment: When I try to install pygame with `pip install -U pygame`, I get a long `gcc` compiler error.

Comment: IMO, that last line of the error message is the least informative of them all

Comment: Here's a more expanded summary. The whole thing didn't fit in Stack Overflow's character limit so I had to remove some parts.

Comment: I think you should open an issue on GitHub about this

Comment: Alright then, I'll go raise the issue.